# jQuery validation different errors

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-validate

I have a simple html form, with multiple inputs.

I'm using jQuery validation to change de background color of these inputs when the user hit the submit button withouth filling them correctly (I know this is not ideal, but the field names are self explanatory and a red background is enough for me).

However, some of the fields, are type=radio or type=checkbox and I can't change their background colors. I wanted to change the text color of this fields to red, or change the background color of the text to red.
I don't how to have two different classes applied to different elements from the jQuery validation.

Here are the relevant pieces of my code:

JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#registerForm").validate({
            rules: {
                firstname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                lastname: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                },
                gender: {
                    required: true  
                },
                policy: "required"
            },
            errorClass: 'invalidField'
    });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input id="firstname" name="firstname" />

<input id="lastname" name="lastname" />

<input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male" />Masculino
<input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female" />Feminino

<input type="checkbox" id="policy" name="policy" value="accept" />Eu li e aceito os termos acima
```

CSS:

```
.invalidField {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please explain this again.  The code **as you've posted it** is already giving an error message with a red background on `radio` and `checkboxes`.  What exactly do you want to do differently than what you're already doing here?  http://jsfiddle.net/ZU82g/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the whole code. It's too big. I just put there the parts I thought were necessary.
I removed the error messages in my complete code. I just want to highlight the missing fields.

I managed to do that with Connor McArthur's answer. I just need a way now to remove the highlight when the user selects the checkbox or radio input.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<input id="firstname" name="firstname" />

<input id="lastname" name="lastname" />

<div>
    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="male" />
    <span class="highlightMe">Masculino</span>

    <br/>

    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="female" />
    <span class="highlightMe">Feminino</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.invalidField {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
}

.invalidField ~ .highlightMe {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I wanted.
I don't know what that tilde does in css, but ir worked.

However, the highlight won't go out once the user selects the checkbox or radio button.
Any idea how to remove it?

Thanks.

Comment: The `~` in CSS indicates a sibling. You'll need to remove the `invalidField` class from the radio in order to get the highlight to go away.

Comment: And how do I remove that? The jQuery validation seems to do it automatically when I fill a field.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the jQuery validation library, but you might be able to use the `onclick` option: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate

Answer (score 1):

you could try errorPlacement.
put this after the open bracket in the validate function:

```
$("#registerForm").validate({ 
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
       if (element.attr("name") == "elementName") {
            $(element).css('background-color', '#ffdddd')
       }
    }, // continue your validation code (rules + errorclass)    
});
```

change 'elementName' to the name of your input. 
You could change the element.attr() == '' to test if it was type=radio or type=checkbox.

Comment: This works to apply different stylings to different input types, but I can't target the radio input or the checkbox's input text with this.
The text stays outside the <input> tag and it's not affected...

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use the same class on each element from jQuery validate but use a more specific CSS rule to get what you want for coloration, example:

```
.invalidField {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
}
input[type=checkbox].invalidField,
input[type=radio].invalidField {
    color: #ffdddd;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what I wanted by adding some specif JS to the radio and checkbox inputs. Here's what I did:

JS:

```
$('#policy').change(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $('.policyError').css('background-color', '#ffffff')
    }
    else {
        $('.policyError').css('background-color', '#ffdddd')
    }
});
$('.gender').change(function() {
    $('.genderError').css('background-color', '#ffffff')
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" value="male" ><span class="genderError">Masculino</span>
<input type="radio" class="gender" name="gender" value="female" /><span class="genderError">Feminino</span>
<input type="checkbox" id="policy" name="policy" value="accept" /><span class="policyError">Eu li e aceito os termos acima</span>
```

CSS:

```
.invalidField {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
}
.invalidField ~ .genderError {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
}
.invalidField ~ .policyError {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
}
```

Comment: See my answer.  You can put your code inside the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback functions and make it a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use  the `highlight` and `unhighlight` callback function options.  Start with the defaults and just edit them to do something different on `radio` and `checkbox` elements.

I've already modified the default by altering the conditional statement to look for `radio` or `checkbox` elements.  These callbacks fire for each element as each element is validated.

- `hightlight` fires whenever there is an error on a particular element.
- `unhighlight` fires whenever a particular element passes validation.

You just need to tweak the one part of each of these two functions to do whatever styling you need to those elements.

```
    highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if (element.attr("type") === "radio" || element.attr("type") === "checkbox") {
            // change this line to add special 'error' styling to radio and checkbox elements
            this.findByName(element.attr("name")).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if (element.attr("type") === "radio" || element.attr("type") === "checkbox") {
            // change this line to remove the special 'error' styling to radio and checkbox elements
            this.findByName(element.attr("name")).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        }
    },
```

In the demo I used your code from [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15527491/594235).

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/qwj5S/**

```
   highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if ($(element).attr("name") === "gender") {
            $('.genderError').addClass('invalidField');
        } else if ($(element).attr("name") === "policy") {
            $('.policyError').addClass('invalidField');
        } else {
            $(element).addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass);
        }
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
        if ($(element).attr("name") === "gender") {
            $('.genderError').removeClass('invalidField');
        } else if ($(element).attr("name") === "policy") {
            $('.policyError').removeClass('invalidField');
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass);
        }
    },
```

**CSS**:

No special CSS.  This uses the same `invalidField` class since it shares the same properties.